# toString function in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, I was reading about scala from the following source: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/classes

It had the following code:

```
class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int) {
  def move(dx: Int, dy: Int): Unit = {
    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
  }
  override def toString: String =
    "(" + x + ", " + y + ")"
}
object Classes {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pt = new Point(1, 2)
    println(pt)
    pt.move(10, 10)
    println(pt)
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
(1, 2)
(11, 12)
```

I wanted to ask how did the `println(pt)` function printed the result `(1,2)`? Should we not call `pt.toString()` to print the result as shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an overload of `println` that accepts a value of type `Any` (in [Predef.scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Predef$.html)):

```
def println(x: Any) = Console.println(x)
```

Deep inside, it calls `x.toString()` to get the string to print.

Comment: What if we used a different name for the method toString say ToString, but which does the same thing, will the println know how to print the object now?

Comment: No - `toString` overrides Java's `Object.toString` which is the method eventually called by `println`. If you don't override it - the default implementation (which prints the class name and memory address) will be used, and NOT any other method that you create.

Comment: Where can I find the implementation of the prinln() function?

Comment: Start here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L393 - then you'll have to drill down into Console.scala, PrintStream.java and String.java

Comment: Note that Scala inherits this feature from Java, where `System.out.println(obj);` will also call `toString()` on `obj`. So you probably won't find it in the Scala source.